# Why does my Ubuntu run on low-graphic mode?

Tags: nvidia, xorg

My graphic card is Nvidia GTX 460 and I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

I have reinstalled graphic driver for two times, but my Ubuntu shows that it runs on low-graphic mode after a period of time of driver installation process. The following is the information the computer shows.

[image: Image 1]

Also, when I try to change the graphic setting of Nvidia on Ubuntu, the following information shows.

[image: Image 2]

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you install the graphics driver from the official nvidia homepage? There you can get an installer which sets it up for you. You have to shutdown the gnome display manager and then you execute the file. This installer also creates a kernel module for you. If you already used this driver installer, please attach your /etc/X11/xorg.conf if it exists. Also your X11 server log file would be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelK Answer it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [Micheal K](https://askubuntu.com/users/29216/michael-k) in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87703/why-does-my-ubuntu-run-on-low-graphic-mode#comment100002_87703):

> Did you install the graphics driver from the official nvidia homepage?
>
> There you can get an installer which sets it up for you. You have to
>   shutdown the gnome display manager and then you execute the file.
>
> This installer also creates a kernel module for you. If you already
>   used this driver installer, please attach your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if
>   it exists. Also your X11 server log file would be helpful.